# Sorting with csv library, error says my dates don't match '%Y-%m-%d' format when it does

Tags: csv, datetime, strptime

I'm trying to sort a CSV by date first then time second. With Pandas, it was easy by using `df = df.sort_values(by=['Date', 'Time_UTC'])`. In the csv library, the code is (from here):

```
with open ('eqph_csv_29May2020_noF_5lines.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',') 
    date_sorted = sorted(reader, key=lambda Date: datetime.strptime('Date', '%Y-%m-%d'))
    print(date_sorted)
```

The [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) clearly says these codes are right. Here's a sample CSV (no delimiter):

```
Date    Time_UTC    Latitude    Longitude
2020-05-28  05:17:31    16.63   120.43
2020-05-23  02:10:27    15.55   121.72
2020-05-20  12:45:07    5.27    126.11
2020-05-09  19:18:12    14.04   120.55
2020-04-10  18:45:49    5.65    126.54
```

Comment: `datetime.strptime('Date', '%Y-%m-%d')` should be `datetime.strptime(Date, '%Y-%m-%d')`, you're trying to parse the literal string `'Date'` as a date.

Comment: I already tried that but it says `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not dict` and same error but ...`not list` if the CSV is read with `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` returns an iterator that yields a `dict` for each row in the csv file. To sort it on a column from each row, you need to specify that column in the sort function:

```
date_sorted = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

To sort on both `Date` and `Time_UTC`, you could combine them into one string and convert that to a `datetime`:

```
date_sorted = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row['Date'] + ' ' + row['Time_UTC'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: I actually solved it by using `csv.reader()` instead of `csv.DictReader()`. But I only sorted it out by date, and not time. Thanks for showing me how. I'll put my revised code below.

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer worked and used it to revise mine. I used csv.reader() instead.

```
lon,lat = [],[]
xy = zip(lon,lat)

with open ('eqph_csv_29May2020_noF_20lines.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',') 
    next(reader)
    date_sorted = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime
                         (row[0] + ' ' + row[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))   
    for row in date_sorted:
        lon.append(float(row[2]))
        lat.append(float(row[3]))
for i in xy:
    print(i)
```

Result

```
(6.14, 126.2)
(14.09, 121.36)
(13.74, 120.9)
(6.65, 125.42)
(6.61, 125.26)
(5.49, 126.57)
(5.65, 125.61)
(11.33, 124.64)
(11.49, 124.42)
(15.0, 119.79) # 2020-03-19 06:33:00
(14.94, 120.17) # 2020-03-19 06:49:00
(6.7, 125.18)
(5.76, 125.14)
(9.22, 124.01)
(20.45, 122.12)
(5.65, 126.54)
(14.04, 120.55)
(5.27, 126.11)
(15.55, 121.72)
(16.63, 120.43)
```